Python decorator for class methods does not accept arguments from class attributes
I have a conditional decorator that executes action if 'True' is passed, it works great on standalone functions, but when trying to use it on class methods, I cannot pass an argument from class attribute.
Here is how it works on a standalone function:
# decorator with arguments
class MyDec(object):
    def __init__(self,flag):
        self.verbose = flag
    def __call__(self, original_func):
        decorator_self = self
        def wrapper( *args, **kwargs):
            if decorator_self.verbose:
                print('in decorator action')
            original_func(*args,**kwargs)
        return wrapper


@MyDec(True)
def bar():
    print ('in function (decorated) action')

bar()

# output
'''
in decorator action
in function (decorated) action
'''

@MyDec(False)
def bar():
    print ('in function (decorated) action')

bar()

# output
'''
in function(decorated) action
'''

But when I try to use in on a class method, I cannot pass the verbose argument from class init attributes:
class One:
    def __init__(self, verbose):
        self.verbose = verbose

    @MyDec(self.verbose)
    def print_something(self):
        print('in decorated func action')

one = One(False)
one.print_something()

# output
'''
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
'''

I've tried creating global variables/local variables and passing them, but nothing works. Please help.

You get that error when the class body is going to get executed. In that stage you don't even have any instance of your One class so self cannot exist.
Just like other functions in global, pass the actual value:
class One:
    def __init__(self, verbose):
        self.verbose = verbose

    @MyDec(True)
    def print_something(self):
        print("in decorated func action")

Your method definitions cannot depend on the instance's value. The method creation happens before any instance creation.
You may need to put that flag's value inside some other instances(of other classes) and use it inside your One class.
Or re-write the decorator so that it works for the classes whose instances have the .verbose attribute:
def my_dec(fn):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        instance = args[0]
        if instance.verbose:
            print("in decorator action")
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)

    return inner

Then use it like:
class One:
    def __init__(self, verbose):
        self.verbose = verbose

    @my_dec
    def print_something(self):
        print("in decorated func action")


one = One(True)
one.print_something()


But I need to control this verbosity using class arguments. Otherwise what's the point in passing any argument. For instance if I run the class methods in debug mode, I want them to output information, if not in debug mode, then I don't want decorator to execute.

Just noticed your last part of the answer: crate another class instance... Shouldn't there be a more elegant way?

@Danil check the updated answer.

That works, thanks!

@Danil Happy to help. You can upvote and mark the answer as accepted if it helped you.
